# Flask Callback when Application Context is Available

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

I have a function that I want to call that generates a set of urls. However, to fully generate the urls (using `url_for()`) I need to have an application context that's available with `SERVER_NAME` set.

I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve setting `SERVER_NAME` explicitly, but instead a solution that would involve running my function as soon as a full application context is available, that is, after a `app.run()` provides a full application context. I'm running this application on uWSGI, so I'm looking for a solution that works with the uWSGI initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`before_first_request`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.before_first_request) hook to run the code once, inside the application context, and after the server is fully initialised.

Comment: I'm assuming there isn't an equivalent callback for after server startup is there?

before_first_request normally should work, but this code contains some performance intensive sections. I wouldn't really want to run it during any regular request traffic.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but in general performance intensive code shouldn't depend on the web server, so you might want to rethink your design and consider background queues or scheduled jobs.